# Detect object field in Inspector window was changed

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

How do I write a logic in script to detect if the object field has been changed in inspector window? I am using a script that executes in editor as well as play mode and I am altering `OffsetPosition` in the inspector window. The offset position is then copied to my GameObject. I want a function to detect if the gameObject has been changed in inspector window.

```
    public GameObject Offset;
    public Vector3 OffsetPosition; 
    public bool GameObject_NotChanged;

    void Update () {
         if(GameObject_NotChanged == true)
         {
           Offset.transform.position = OffsetPosition;
         }
    }

    void GameObject_Changed()
    {
       GameObject_NotChanged = false;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`OnValidate`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnValidate.html)

> This function is called when the script is loaded or a value is changed in the Inspector (Called in the editor only).

like so

```
public GameObject Offset;
public Vector3 OffsetPosition; 

private GameObject _lastOffset;
private Vector3 _lastOffsetPosition;

private void OnValidate()
{
    if((Offset != _lastOffset || _lastOffsetPosition != OffsetPosition))
    {
        if(Offset)
        {
            Offset.transform.position = OffsetPosition;
        }
        

        _lastOffsetPosition = OffsetPosition;
        _lastObject = Offset;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks. But how do I re add ```Offset.transform.position = OffsetPosition;``` with the new offset gameObject?

Comment: @Amar.linsila sorry I don't quite understand the question .. did you mean to also re-assign if you change the `OffsetPosition`? -> Just updated the answer to do this as well

Comment: Perfect! Thanks alot. Exactly what I was looking for.